# Suppress dialog in Excel automation

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

After an current update of Excel/Office365 to version 16.03.13127.21064 (64bit) the below dialog (Others are also making changes) pops up if I open a file with VBScript.

[image]

I already use `Application.DisplayAlers = False` in my VBScript to suppress dialogues, but for this dialog the setting has no effect.

This is my script:

```
Option Explicit

Dim inputFile
Dim macroName
Dim xlApp 
Dim xlBook 

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
xlApp.Visible = False
xlApp.EnableEvents = False
         
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(inputFile) 
xlApp.Run macroName

'...
```

Is there another option to switch Excel in a kind of interactive mode.

Thank you for help
Andreas

Comment: May I see a minimal version of your vbscript code?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Yes, of course. I added a snippet in my post.

Comment: Thanks. I just noticed you have a 64 bit version. I have a 32 bit version (16.03.13714.20000). So I was unable to (obviously) replicate it. Hopefully someone can test this.

Comment: BTW is the file on a network drive?

Comment: If you are the only one using this file and still getting this message then try this for me **1.** Open the file **2.** Save the file using `File | Save As` **3.** Check the above code with the new file.

Comment: Yes the file is on a "network drive". The file is hosted on Sharepoint and synced with OneDrive to my computer.

Comment: Try resaving the file as i mentioned above and use the new file and see if you are still getting the alert